# Darle la vuelta a un array

Tags: java, array

Después de realizar la practica de copiar el contenido de un array en otro, ahora necesito eso y además mostrar el array dado la vuelta. Pero no lo consigo. Este es mi código

```
public class arrayHola {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        char b[]={'h','o','l','a'};
        char c[]= new char[b.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i <b.length; i++) {
            c[i] = b[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<b.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al imprimir c se muestre asi:
a
l
o
h

Comment: y si lo podes recorrer de adelante para atras.. tambien podrias recorrerlo de atras para adelante, no?

Comment: A lo que se refiere bianchi es que puedes hacer el recorrido con el for de manera inversa, si ahora estas sumando y partiendo desde 0, puedes restar y partir desde el final de tu array.

Answer (score 1):

A mi forma de ver es aprovechar el recorrido que haces del FOR para crear el otro array, algo como esto:

```
public class arrayHola {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        char b[]={'h','o','l','a'};
        char c[]= new char[b.length];
        char r[]= new char[b.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i <b.length; i++) {
            c[i] = b[i];
            r[i]=  b[(b.length-1)-i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<b.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(c[i]);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<r.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(r[i]);
        }
}
```

}